# How to find the supremum and infimum of $f(x)=x\sin\frac{1}{x}$ over the interval $(0,\frac{2}{\pi})$?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

How to find the supremum and infimum of $f(x)=x\sin\frac{1}{x}$ over the interval $(0,\frac{2}{\pi})$?

I have shown that supremum is $\frac{2}{\pi}$. How to find infimum.

Comment: No, $f(1/\pi)=0$. Also, the points at which $f(x)=\pm x$ are not the local maxima/minima: for example, $f(x)$ is still decreasing at $x=2/(3\pi)$.

Comment: The infimum is $-0.21723362821122165740827932556247073422$.